# visualizing and "plotting" polynomials as vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, polynomials, soft-question

I'm looking for a clear analogy to describe polynomials as vectors, preferable visually.

In 2-D, the vectors 
$$
\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}
$$
are "plottable" in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We can take the coordinates of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ under the canonical basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_1$ and $\mathbf{e}_2$, plot the coefficients as points, draw arrows to them from the origin, and call them our vectors. Next, I see how to add any such vectors together, scale them, and I can visually see how they span $\mathbb{R}^2$.

In $\mathcal{P}_1$, the space of degree-1 polynomials, how am I supposed to think about the vectors 
$$
\tilde{\mathbf{x}} = 1 + 2x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} , \quad \tilde{\mathbf{y}} = 3 + 4x = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
in the basis $\{1,x\}$. I understand how $\{1,x\}$ span $\mathcal{P}_1$ algebraically, but I'm struggling to (1) visualize $\tilde{\mathbf{x}}$ and $\tilde{\mathbf{y}}$ as points in an appropriate space; and (2) "draw the line from the origin to these points" to visually represent them as vectors in the right space with basis $\{1,x\}$. Basically, I can repeat the tagline that in functional analysis, functions themselves are points, but I'm having trouble visualizing this.

EDIT: I'm having trouble with the idea that for polynomials, the basis functions can take values over $\mathbb{R}$. Based on this, I want to "plot" $v_1 = [1, 1/4]^{\top}$ and $v_2 = [1, 0]^{\top}$ somehow in 3-D like the below, where I feel that the "span" should somehow cover all three axes, though I feel that there's something wrong with this. [image]

Comment: Is the characterization you have already given (of $1+2x$ being represented by $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$) not already suitable for visualization's sake? Is there something more specific you are looking for?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the idea that $1+2x$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$ and how to represent this visually. Intuitively, I want to draw this with a standard $x-y$ two-axis plot.

Comment: The evaluation to a real number is an inconsequential distraction in this case, you should ignore it. $1, x, x^2…$ are just placeholders, the important aspect is the coefficients and the rules they follow in addition, scaling (and if applicable, dot products).

Comment: I agree with @Macavity as the vector space over polynomials is about the coefficients, not the polynomial itself. When working with these vector spaces I mentally substitute $x_k$ for $x^k$ to remind myself of this.

Comment: Thanks @Macavity -- can you elaborate on why I should ignore evaluation to a real number?

Comment: @jjjjjj Because it is irrelevant. Why do you think it is relevant / should be considered when looking at polynomials as a vector space?

Comment: Because I can "plot" them when they evaluate to a real number and visualize this easily. That is, plotting the coefficients amounts to plotting the vectors themselves. I want to see why I can or can't do this for $\{1,x,\ldots\}$.

Comment: If you have the irresistible urge to plot them differently than traditional vectors, you could do so of course in $2D$ itself, $y=P(x)$  can be plotted easily enough for any number of polynomials. Not sure if it helps in anyway, addition will be addition of the graphs, scaling is scaling the graph and so on. Inner products and in general angles will cease to make much visual sense.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to think about this. Is there no nice way of visualizing the span of $\{1,x\}$ by plotting $y=P(x)$? I tried something that felt like nonsense in the attached picture...